# link logic class into my gui class java

Tags: java, user-interface

hello i was wondering how do i link my logic class to my gui class?
i have wrote a logic class which is the structure then had to give it an interface; so i wrote another class which is the gui class but idk how to make the GUI class grab the variable from the logic class.
P.S: its a number guessing game that the user has to guess a numb btw 1-10.

**LOGIC CLASS**

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GG {


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //random number
        Random rand = new Random();
        int answer = rand.nextInt(10) +1;
        int guess = 0;
        int attempts = 0;
        public 

        //user's guess

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


        GuessingGameGui gui = new GuessingGameGui();
        gui.setVisible(true);


        while(answer != guess)
        {
            try
            {

                System.out.print("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ");
                attempts++;
                guess = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (guess < 1 || guess > 10)
                    //throw new BadGuessException()  
                    throw new BadGuessException("invalid entry (" + attempts + " attempts so far)");
            }
            catch (BadGuessException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter integers only, and try again");
                keyboard.next(); //to get rid of infinite loop issue
            }
        }

        System.out.println("YOU GOT IT (" + attempts + "attempts )");

    }

}
```

GUI CLASS

```
public class GuessingGameGui extends JFrame {

    public GuessingGameGui() {

        final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 650;   // Window width in pixels
        final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 250;  // Window height in pixels

        setTitle("Guessing Game");

        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        JPanel north = new JPanel();
        JLabel lab1 = new JLabel("Guess a number between 1 and 10?");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
        north.add(lab1);
        add( north );

        JPanel center = new JPanel();

        final JTextField titleText = new JTextField();
        titleText.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 24 ) );
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton button = new JButton("Guess");
        Action action = new AbstractAction()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String typed = titleText.getText();
                int guess = Integer.parseInt(typed);
            }
        };

        titleText.addActionListener( action );

        button.addActionListener( action );
        center.add(titleText);
        center.add(button);
        add( center );

        JPanel south = new JPanel();
        JLabel lab2 = new JLabel("YOU GOT IT " + attempts);
        south.add(lab2);
        add( south );

       }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean with link? There are a thousand ways to do it. Please be more specific.

Comment: @Alexander basically i want when i type: JLabel lab2 = new JLabel("YOU GOT IT " + attempts); to grab the number of attempts and show it. i looked up online and i think i have to make getters for it?

Comment: Checkout the Model View Controller design pattern http://www.newthinktank.com/2013/02/mvc-java-tutorial/ this guy's tutorials are great for beginners

Answer (score 1):

A common way is to add the Logic object to the GUI, for example through the constructor. Then whenever something is happening on the GUI you need to call the correct methods on the Logic object and update the display if needed.